# Problem to get z-score plot with boruta R

Tags: r, feature-selection, boruta

I am working with Boruta R package for selection variable.

I am trying to replicate plots from Maya Gopal and Bhargavi: FEATURE  SELECTION FOR YIELD PREDICTION USING BORUTA ALGORITHM (2018).

https://acadpubl.eu/hub/2018-118-22/articles/22a/19.pdf

Lamentably I can not get the z-score plot evolution during Boruta run from this paper.[image: Fig 2]

An example of my script is:

```
   library(Boruta)

   boruta_model <- Boruta(lag ~ ., 
    data=tesis33, 
    doTrace=2, 
    maxRuns = 100,
    getImp = getImpRfZ) 

   plot(boruta_model)
```

I did try with this commands but lamentably dont work for my:

```
plotZScore(boruta_model)
plotZHistory(boruta_model)
```